# CGContextDrawImage causes EXC BAD ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, exc-bad-access, cgcontext

Those few lines of code cause EXC BAD ACCESS. Clearly self.thumbnailimage is not nil(i check it). So what could it be?

```
  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    if(self.thumbnailImage)
    {
        CGContextDrawImage(context,CGRectMake(14, 5, 58, 58), self.thumbnailImage);
    }
```

Comment: what kind of class is thumbnaailImage?

Comment: thumbnailImage should be CGImageRef

Comment: Well, it is. It is created by method something like jpegdatawithuiimage, saved to core data, then extracted with something like [uiimage  imagewithnsdata] and then I call [image cgimage] and draw it

Answer (score 0):

Well, problem solved. I ended up using uiimage method drawInRect